# How to load external local JS file

Tags: vue.js

I have an external JS file that calls an external API but I'm unable to call the file in Vue when it's stored locally. How do you do this?

The following works perfectly fine and connects to the API.

```
const cnp = document.createElement('script');
cnp.setAttribute('src', https://example.com/cnp.js);
document.head.appendChild(cnp);
```

This or any other variation of this doesn't work.

```
const cnp = document.createElement('script');
cnp.setAttribute('src', '@/js/cnp.js');
document.head.appendChild(cnp);
```

cnp.js contains

```
console.log('Hello');

var wpwlOptions = {
    style: "plain",
    onReady: function() {
        console.log('wpwlReady.');

        var p = document.querySelector('form.wpwl-form-card');
        p.style.background = 'none';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use js modules for that.

1.Export functionality from cnp.js file.

Add `export default cnp;`in the end of the file if you want to export all of it.
Or if you want to export certain variables you can do as so:

```
export var wpwlOptions = () => {
    ...
}
```

2.Import it whenever you need:

```
import cnp from "@/js/cnp";
```

Or if you want to export certain variable:

```
import { wpwlOptions } from "@/js/cnp";
```

Answer (score 0):

PLACE IN PUBLIC FOLDER; Any static assets placed in the public folder will simply be copied and not go through webpack. You need to reference them using absolute paths.

Therefore, you can place your external JS within public folder and use its path to execute your JS file. For more reference follow https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#html

Since it will not go through webpack, it is not the recommended way to do so. I would recommend you to place this JS call within any Vue lifecycle hook, since placing it in public folder is not a good practice.